# I can't get my web form to post to the database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation

The database is connected - but I can't seem to insert a new record. 
The database has been created, the table is created, but my form won't work.

I have to be able to add new users, verify the password - but I have been able to work out this part.

I have tried many times - different code - I am not sure if it's syntax error or variables etc.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            color:black;
            background-color:#6BDBAF;
        }
        h1{
           color: #177A58; 
           font: 48px arial, sans-serif; 
           font-weight: bold; 
           text-align: center; padding: 3px;
           text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
        }
        h2,h3,h4{
            color:#177A58;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
        }
        .banner{
            height:25px;
            width:100%;
            color:green;
            background-color:#177A53;
            font:arial bold 15/25px;
            text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
        }

        .menu a {
          margin-left: 50px;
          margin-right: 50px;
          padding: auto;
          width: auto;
          height: 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
          color:white;
          font: 15px/25px Helvetica, sans-serif, solid;
        }

        .menu a:hover {
          background: #00CC66;
        }

        #login-form{
            positive: relative;
        }
        td{
            min-width: 100px;
        }

        .form-container {
           border: 2px solid #38875a;
           background: #060f0e;
           background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#177A53), to(#060f0e));
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #177A53, #060f0e);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #177A53, #060f0e);
           background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #177A53, #060f0e);
           background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #177A53, #060f0e);
           background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #177A53 0%, #060f0e 100%);
           -webkit-border-radius: 26px;
           -moz-border-radius: 26px;
           border-radius: 26px;
           -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.9) 0 1px 2px, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
           -moz-box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.9) 0 1px 2px, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
           box-shadow: rgba(000,000,000,0.9) 0 1px 2px, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
           font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif;
           text-decoration: none;
           vertical-align: middle;
           min-width:500px;
           padding:20px;
           width:70%;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
         }

        .form-field {
           border: 1px solid #c9b7a2;
           background: #84ba94;
           -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
           -moz-border-radius: 8px;
           border-radius: 8px;
           color: #194221;
           -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000,000,000,0.7) 0 1px 1px;
           -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000,000,000,0.7) 0 1px 1px;
           box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(000,000,000,0.7) 0 1px 1px;
           padding:8px;
           margin-bottom:20px;
           width:80%;
        }

        .form-field:focus {
           background: #fff;
           color: #020504;
        }

        .form-container h2 {
           text-shadow: #0a1f17 0 1px 0;
           font-size:18px;
           margin: 0 0 10px 0;
           font-weight:bold;
           text-align:center;

            }
        .form-title {
           margin-bottom:20px;
           margin-left: 40px;
           color: white;
           text-shadow: #0a1f17 0 1px 0;

        }

        .Submit-container {
           margin:8px 0;
           text-align:right;
        }

        .Submit {
           border: 2px solid #26402e;
           background: #424a44;
           background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4a9e65), to(#424a44));
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4a9e65, #424a44);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4a9e65, #424a44);
           background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4a9e65, #424a44);
           background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4a9e65, #424a44);
           background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4a9e65 0%, #424a44 100%);
           -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
           -moz-border-radius: 11px;
           border-radius: 11px;
           -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
           -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
           box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
           text-shadow: #384728 0 1px 0;
           color: #070a05;
           font-family: helvetica, serif;
           padding: 8.5px 18px;
           font-size: 14px;
           text-decoration: none;
           vertical-align: middle;
           float: left;
           width: 300px;
        }

        .Submit:hover {
           border: 2px solid #7bc7b4;
           text-shadow: #31540c 0 1px 0;
           background: #88bfb1;
           background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#357a5e), to(#88bfb1));
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #357a5e, #88bfb1);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #357a5e, #88bfb1);
           background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #357a5e, #88bfb1);
           background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #357a5e, #88bfb1);
           background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #357a5e 0%, #88bfb1 100%);
           color: #fff;
        }

        .Submit:active {
           text-shadow: #31540c 0 1px 0;
           border: 2px solid #447314;
           background: #48a67c;
           background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#394231), to(#88bfb1));
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #394231, #48a67c);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #394231, #48a67c);
           background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #394231, #48a67c);
           background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #394231, #48a67c);
           background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #394231 0%, #48a67c 100%);
           color: #fff;
        }

    .report{
        color: grey;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body>


  <div class="banner">
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="index.php" class="one">Home</a>
        <a href="resume.html" class="two">About</a>
        <a href="gallery.php" class="three">ArtGallery</a>
        <a href="checkout.php" class="four">Shop</a>
        <a href="register.php" class="five">Register</a>
        <a href="theory.html" class="six">ArtTheory</a>
        <a href="account.php" class="seven">MyAccount</a>
        <a href="userlogin.php" class="eight">UserLogin</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Website Sign Up</h1>

        <form action="register.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="true"/>

            <table class="form-container">
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">Enter User Email:* </td><td><input type="text" name="loginEmail" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">Enter a Password:* </td><td><input type="text" id="password" name="password" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">First Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">Last Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">Street Address: </td><td><input type="text"  name="street" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">City: </td><td><input type="text" name="city" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">State: </td><td><input type="text" name="state" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">Postcode: </td><td><input type="text" name="zip" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label class="form-title">Phone: </td><td><input type="text" name="phone" class="form-field" value=""/></label></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="Submit" class="Submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
            </table>

        <br />

        </form>
<div class="report">

<?php
include ('libcommon.php');

mysql_select_db($membersDB,$conn);
    if (!$membersDB) {
            echo mysql_error();
        }else{
            echo "<p>Successfully connected to the <em>MembersDirectory</em> database: Waiting for new record...";
        }


// query
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MembersDirectory;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (loginEmail,password,firstName,lastName,street,city,state,zip,phone) 
    VALUES (:loginEmail,:password,:fname,:lname,:street,:city,:state,:zip,:phone)");
$q->execute(array(':loginEmail'=>$uname,
                  ':password'=>$pwd,
                  ':firstName'=>$fname,
                  ':lastName'=>$lname,
                  ':street'=>$Street,
                  ':city'=>$City,
                  ':state'=>$State,
                  ':zip'=>$PostCd,
                  ':phone'=>$Phone));

?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors, if any? What output, if any? Run `print_r()` throughout to confirm you're getting the expected values.

Comment: Also, use PDO functions, not mysql* functions to avoid SQL injection risks.

Comment: stop! inserting unsantised user input will get you hacked before you can say www

Comment: storing plain text passwords is also super bad

Comment: Please show your table structure

Comment: what are PDO and where do you use printr()?

Comment: $sqlMembers = "CREATE TABLE members (
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    loginEmail VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    createDate TIMESTAMP,
    firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    street VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    city VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    state VARCHAR(3) NULL,
    zip INT NULL,
    phone INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id))";

Comment: this is an assignment - i am trying to get it to work for submission

Comment: add this to the top of your PHP files `<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: who ever is still teaching mysql_* should be fired(out of a canon(at @Fred-ii-'s house))

Comment: I can't wait for the circus to come to town @Dagon

Comment: Like this `mysql_query($newMember,$conn) or die(mysql_error());` I didn't have time to edit my other comment. Stack should increase that to say... an hour! lol plus, you have don't have a closing `</div>`.

Comment: this doesn't do much really `if($newMember !=='') {
    echo "complete all fields!";`

Comment: error reporting with your present code, is most likely giving you undefined index notices... but, you're not sharing any of those notices. wishing you well with your project.

Comment: @Dagon we'll have to skip on the popcorn. I think I'll go watch me some canon home videos now.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of security problems here:

1. You're inserting 'unsafe' data straight into the database, without validating it. Ideally, you'd have a list of valid inputs to compare to (whitelisting). You COULD have a blacklist, but thats likely to be incomplete.
2. You're creating a string containing unsafe data, then executing it! This means you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider if the user types `'; UPDATE users SET password = 'lol';` - they're able to execute any SQL they want!
3. You're storing passwords in plaintext. If anyone has access to the database, legitimately (developers/admins) or otherwise (hackers), they can see the user's passwords.
4. You're using the root database user, with a default/empty password. For a serious system, don't do that. You'd also want to store the database password elsewhere (some config or keystore), no straight in the source. And the server name, etc, too.

Regarding #1, perhaps don't worry TOO much. PHP has some validation/sanitization functions. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) if you're interested. It may be worth at least checking that all of those keys exist in the `$_POST` array though. Try iterating through every expected key, confirm that `array_key_exists($key, $_POST)`, and error out if not.

To solve #2, we should really rewrite that PHP script to use PDO, rather than mysql functions. [This](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) gives a good tutorial. Ideally, we'd also be doing some error handling (try-catch, set error display mode to the strictest, etc). Essentially, you want to:

```
// Establish a connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
// Prepare a query
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5)");
// Execute a query
$stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $field1, ':field2' => $field2, ':field3' => $field3, ':field4' => $field4, ':field5' => $field5));
// Close the connection
$db = null;
```

To solve #3, save the hash of a password, rather than the plaintext. A hash is a one-way encrypted version of some data, such that you can convert the plaintext to the hash, but can't convert a hash to the plaintext. So if someone gets access to your database, they won't be able to determine the passwords. So, we store passwords as `password_hash($input)` rather than `$input`, and compare with `password_verify($usersAttempt, $valueInDb)` rather than `$usersAttempt === $valueInDb`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) for more info.

Comment: could add checking the form is submitted - bet there are a ton of unset variable notices on firstload

Comment: As in, do some validation to ensure those keys actually exist in the $_POST array?

Comment: the query will run on first load before any one even fills in the form

Comment: Oh, I assumed there was a separate form page and action page.

Comment: i assumed it was one page - lets arm wrestle on it :-)

Comment: I'll get the popcorn @Dagon

Comment: Successfully connected to server.
Successfully connected to the MembersDirectory database: Waiting for new record...
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'membersdirectory'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSC8417\Project\register.php:233 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSC8417\Project\register.php(233): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSC8417\Project\register.php on line 233

Comment: this is the error i am getting

Comment: this is all nice and dandy, but given the OP's experience here Luke, I doubt very much she'll know what to do here. Plus, she'll also have to ALTER the password column to a higher number in order to accommodate password_hash's characters which she has it at 20 right now. and, as for... if the OP's using separate pages or not; it's best to always check with `!empty()` for all inputs. This question's just a tad too off-topic for my taste.

Comment: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MembersDirectory;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (loginEmail,password,firstName,lastName,street,city,state,zip,phone) 
    VALUES (:loginEmail,:password,:fname,:lname,:street,:city,:state,:zip,:phone)");
$q->execute(array(':loginEmail'=>$uname,
                  ':password'=>$pwd,...........and so on.

Comment: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MembersDirectory;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO members (loginEmail,password,firstName,lastName,street,city,state,zip,phone) 
    VALUES (:loginEmail,:password,:fname,:lname,:street,:city,:state,:zip,:phone)");
$q->execute(array(':loginEmail'=>$uname,
                  ':password'=>$pwd,

Comment: the for is on the same page

Comment: i have declared the names of the fields with name='loginEmail' etc is it maybe that they need to be different to the query variables?

Comment: Hahaha Dagon :) I did my best, Fred, hopefully she'll get something from that schpiel. OP: "And so on..." doesn't really help haha! Unknown database, did you get the name correct? It may be case-sensitive, too.

Comment: Just a little off topic, using the root database user with no password is another security hole ;) but as it's an assignment, I wouldn't worry too much. Just something to remember!

Comment: i admit i am new to this - but i have been trying to get this working for days - i am ready to fail this bloody thing to make sure i pass the written assessment but it means a lot to me to do well - i have come this far.

Comment: Haha no problem. Sorry, we're probably overloading you a bit with information. Update your original post with an edit, the new code we're trying, and the errors/output. Persist, you'll get this, don't worry!!

Comment: my website is an artists gallery / shop - i manage to have the install.php create the databases and connections - with test entries that have been successful - i am have trouble with the form data posting to the database - if there is a simpler way to do this please help - but being patronising is not going to help me do that.

Comment: not you luke - dagon

Comment: i really appreciate the help -  this is my last assignment of my masters in computing - i have done everything on my own till now i have never posted anything online before

Comment: Good good! Okay, so now you need to share what's happening versus what you were expecting, and what errors you're seeing?

Comment: Successfully connected to server.
Successfully connected to the MembersDirectory database: Waiting for new record...
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'membersdirectory'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSC8417\Project\register.php:233 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CSC8417\Project\register.php(233): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CSC8417\Project\register.php on line 233

Comment: thats before entering any data

Comment: Is your database definitely called 'MembersDirectory', or 'MembersDirectory'? Remove those lines from `mysql_select_....`. What was the old connection string?

Comment: there is still a problem with this line:$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=MembersDirectory;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

Comment: Yep, I agree. When you called `mysql_select_db()` before, what was the parameter?

Comment: i completely for the createDate field in my table

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that? You're still not giving the info needed!

Answer (score 0):

Add `name` for the submit button like

```
<input type="Submit" class="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

> Note: Name is need for the submit button or input type in the form